# How to add trailing zeros to an integer in python? or How to add ZEROS after any integer in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm without clues on how to do this in Python. The problem is the following: I have for example an orders numbers like:

```
1
2
...
10
```

The output should be

```
1000
2000
...
10000
```

That is I want to add 3 extra zeros after the integer

Comment: did you forget how to multiply?

Comment: Since you're mentioning output, it's probably worth noting that print("%i000"%a) or "{A}000".format(A=a) works for the general case where the characters you wish to append may or may not be numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, the 3 extra zeros are for output purposes only.  There is no need to obtain integers back.  Strings (or for that mater, any other type) is enough.  In this vein, any of

```
print(a*1000)
print(str(a)+"000")
print(a,"000",sep="")
```

and perhaps several others, would work.

Comment: note that since the question references python2.7, you'll need to include `from __future__ import print_function` for the last example to work properly.

Comment: @Perkins It also references python-3.x.  What to understand when a question is tagged with both?  That you have to answer for **both** or for **either** (and that the OP is willing to find out additional details)?  Anyways, your comment will be very useful to people still using 2.7.  Thanks for it! :-)

Comment: Aye, I should have been more clear that by using the future import, it will work with both 3.x and 2.x, since 3.x ignores that future import, if I had thought it was tagged 2.x only, I'd have mentioned the print statement syntax rather than the print function.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by 10 every time you want to add another 0.

This is the same as saying 10 to the power of how many zeroes you want. In python, that would be `number * (10**extraZeroCount)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to append 3 zeroes after every integer like

`int(str(number) + "000")`

But I would just multiply them by 1000

Comment: That would be `str(number) + "000"`.

Comment: woops, i knew something was wrong :P been a while in python, geared to java.